# Non-Schwartz functions in Bourgain space X^{s,b}?

Tags: fourier-analysis, dispersive-pde

From Terence Tao's Nonlinear dispersive equations: local and global analysis, Definition 2.7:

The Bourgain space $X^{s,b}(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n)$ is defined to be the closure of the set of Schwartz functions $\mathcal S_{t,x}(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n)$ under the norm
$$\|u\|_{X^{s,b}}:=\|\langle\xi\rangle^s\langle\tau-h(\xi)\rangle^b\hat u(\tau,\xi)\|_{L_{\tau,\xi}^2}$$
for $\{s,b\}\subset\mathbb R$ and a given continuous function $h:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.

In the definition above I would assume there is a reason it's defined to be the closure of $\mathcal S_{t,x}$ rather than the set of all function such that $\|u\|_{X_{\tau=h(\xi)}^{s,b}}<\infty$. What kinds of functions have finite $X^{s,b}$-norms but are not limits of Schwartz functions? And what kinds of problems, if any, can we encounter with the $\|u\|_{X_{\tau=h(\xi)}^{s,b}}<\infty$ version of the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out why. The Bourgain norm is defined in terms of an $L^2$-norm, and we know the Schwartz function space $\mathcal S$ is dense in $L^2$. Also $\langle\xi\rangle^s\langle\tau-h(\xi)\rangle^b$ is virtually more or less a polynomial* so if $\widehat u\in\mathcal S$ then $\langle\xi\rangle^s\langle\tau-h(\xi)\rangle^b\widehat u\in\mathcal S$ and vice versa. Therefore in fact both versions of definitions are the same. There is no function $u$ such that $\|u\|_{X^{s,b}}<\infty$ as well as $u\notin X^{s,b}$. The reason we think of the closure of $\mathcal S$ is that it tells us what qualifies as a function in a given space; we know $\mathcal S$ is dense in $L^p$, but an $L^p$ function does not have to be the kind of function that we learnt at high school. An $L^p$ function can take $\infty$ as its value at countably many points, and the Sobolev space $H^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ even contains the Dirac delta function $\delta$ which is, in fact, not a function. Just like we can define the sine or cosine function reversely with its Taylor series, we can define the $L^p$ space as the closure of $\mathcal S$, and its variants likewise, such as the Bourgain space $X^{s,b}$, the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$, etc. Such a definition naturally also defines what a function is in the given context.

* For $b<0$ with $h(\xi)$ growing faster than polynomials, things could go wrong, but so far I've never seen the $X^{s,b}$ space used in such a setting, in which we would need something more than tempered distributions if we were to adopt the finite-norm definition. This is maybe pointless in practice.

Comment: Yes, it is often easier to define a function-space "from the inside", as a completion of nice functions with respect to norms (etc) that are immediately sensible things applied to nice functions. Still, on other occasions, we do want to _also_ identify function spaces "from the outside", as being measurable functions... or distributions... or ... satisfying finiteness of some norms or seminorms. And we want to know that the two defns produce the same space. Sometimes the defn "from outside" is messier because the seminorms are messier to define on distributions, etc.